# Hierarchical Query sql

Tags: sql, oracle

UPDATED QUESTION!

I have a table with parent-child attributes:

```
Parent_Id  Child_Id         Atribute1    Atribute2(colour)
---------- ----------       ----------   ----------
            1               name1        null 
            2               name2        null
      1     3               name1.1      null
      3     4               name1.1.1    grenn
      3     5               name1.1.2    green
      3     6               name1.1.3    null
      1     7               name1.2      null
      7     8               name1.2.1    green
      7     9               name1.2.2    green
```

Temporary table, which saves selected values (colors)

```
Colour 
------
noclour
green
```

Hierarchy from table looks like:

```
Name2                 no colour
Name1                 no colour         
  Name 1.1            no colour
    name 1.1.1        green
    name 1.1.2        green
    name 1.1.3        no colour
  Name 1.2            no colour
    name 1.2.1        green
    name 1.2.2        green
```

I saving values in temporary table. If temporary table have value 'nocolour' then result from hierarchy table would be. Result1:

```
Name1               no colour
  Name 1.1          no colour
    name 1.1.3      no colour
```

If temporary table have value 'green' then result would be. Result2

```
Name1               no colour
  Name 1.1          no colour
    name 1.1.1      green
    name 1.1.2      green
  Name 1.2          no colour   
    name 1.2.1      green
    name 1.2.2      green
```

My query:

```
Select * from table
where child_id in (select child_id from table
                   start with nvl(attribrute2, 'nocolour') in (select colour
                                                               from tmp_table)
                   connect by prior parent_id = child_id
                   )
```

If in tmp_table is value green, then my code works fine, i get Result2, but if in tmp_table is value 'nocolour' then i get

```
Name2                  no colour
Name1                  no colour         
  Name 1.1             no colour
    name 1.1.3         no colour
  Name 1.2             no colour
```

But i want get Result1. 
P.S. i don't wan't update parent-child table and change null values to 'nocolour'.
Is there ideas for an answer?

I don't need Name2, when i'm selecting 'no colour', because it hasn't any childs. I don't need Name 1.2, when i'm selecting 'no colour', because Name 1.2 has only childs with colour, then it means, that this parent has childs with no null values ('green' colour).

OK. Can anyone select only null childs? In this example it would be "name 1.1.3 no colour".

Comment: RDBMS? Explain better what's the goal of your query, I think I'm not the only one who don't understant what you try to achieve...

Comment: Added `oracle` tag due to the usage of `connect by`

Comment: Added oracle tag, since `nvl()` and `CONNECT BY ... PRIOR` are very oracle-specific.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude "Name 1.1.3.1"? Sorry, but your problem description isn't very clear.

Comment: There is still information missing from your question. Please consider removing your comments and editing them into your question. Why would you not show `Name2` when searching for `nocolour`?

Comment: How now? Parent depends on childs. Genneraly, in this case parent_id always have not any colour. Perhaps, sometimes, highest parent_id, in this example (Name1) and (name2) may have colour, but never name 1.1, name 1.2 have colour.

Comment: I think, it's too difficulty for stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 0):

This returns all entries, that have at least one recursive child without a color ([SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e16db/13)):

```
SELECT Child_Id, Attribute1
FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL AS lvl, Table1.*
  FROM Table1
  START WITH Attribute2 IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = child_id
)
WHERE lvl > 1
GROUP BY Child_Id, Attribute1
;
```

Result:

```
CHILD_ID    ATTRIBUTE1
1           name1
3           name1.1
6           name1.1.3
```

---

**Edit:** This query returns all records that have a child (non-recursive) with the requested color:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1 parent
 WHERE EXISTS
 (
   SELECT 1
   FROM Table1 child
   WHERE child.Parent_id = parent.Child_Id
   AND NVL(child.Attribute2, 'nocolour') = 'green'
 )
```

Comment: This was not clear from your question. Just add your existing `NVL` to my query and you should be fine.

Comment: I assumed that you did not want `1.1.3.1.1` since it does not have a child with attribute `green`. I won't to be able to answer your question unless you edit it to add more information what you want and why.

Comment: See my edit. If this still does not solve your problem, please update your answer!

Comment: No, it's not. I cannot tell why you want `name 1.1.3.1.1 green` which has no children, but not `Name 1.1.3.1 no colour`.